# Magento 2: Where does M2 create its aliases? uiComponent, in particular?

Tags: magento2, javascript, uicomponent, knockoutjs

In the Knockout/JS files, uiComponent's object is passed to the extending objects in numerous files. I'd like to have a look in the `uiComponent` file but I'm not sure where Magento creates its aliases to find the real name of the file.

Answer (score 1):

The aliases are in `requirejs-config.js` files, of which there are many. The one with `uiComponent` can be found in the `Magento_Ui` module : https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/develop/app/code/Magento/Ui/view/base/requirejs-config.js